# What is difference beetween layout:'hbox' and layout:'column'

Tags: extjs, extjs4

What is difference beetween `layout:'hbox'` and `layout:'column'`? Is it only syntax?

Example '**column**':

```
layout:'column',
items: [{
    title: 'Width = 25%',
    columnWidth: .25,
    html: 'Content'
},{
    title: 'Width = 75%',
    columnWidth: .75,
    html: 'Content'
},{
    title: 'Width = 250px',
    width: 250,
    html: 'Content'
}]
```

Example '**hbox**':

```
layout: {
    type: 'hbox',
    pack: 'start',
    align: 'stretch'
},
items: [
    {html:'panel 1', flex:1},
    {html:'panel 2', width:150},
    {html:'panel 3', flex:2}
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of distinct advantages of `column` that have not been covered.  It is much more lightweight than `hbox`.  `Column` just lets the browser layout its contents with floats instead of setting the `left` it also has less markup than an `hbox`.  It also handles overflows better in most cases.

For example in a column layout vs a hbox on a window

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
    width: 700,
    height: 400,
    title: "Column",
    defaults: {
        height: 50,
        width: 300
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Inner Panel One'
    },{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Inner Panel Two'
    },{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Inner Panel Three'
    }]
});

win.show()

var win2 = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
    width: 700,
    height: 400,
    title: "Hbox",
    defaults: {
        height: 50,
        width: 300
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Inner Panel One'
    },{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Inner Panel Two'
    },{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Inner Panel Three'
    }]
});

win2.show()
```

[image: 600px resize]

[image: 300px resize]

To sum it up think of `column` as an `auto` layout that floats things to the left and `hbox` as a `box` layout which adds the functionality like `stretch` and `pack`.  They both have their versions of flexing.

Answer (score 3):

`Column` existed in an earlier version of the framework before `VBox` and `HBox`. It's mostly been kept for compatibility reasons. `HBox` offers more functionality (`pack` and `align`), amongst other things.

Answer (score 2):

> Column 
>   doesn't have autoheight and HBox does, all the region is full.

Take a look at these examples :

> http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html