# Difference between column and hBox layout

Tags: extjs, extjs4

As far as I can tell, the **hBox** layout in **extJS** seems kind of redundant.

This layout would make the first element 25%, and the second 75%

```
layout: {
    type: 'hbox'
    align : 'stretch',
    pack  : 'start',
},
items: [
    {html:'a', flex:1},
    {html:'b', flex:3}
]
```

But I could just as easily do this with a column layout like so :

```
layout:'column',
items: [
{html: 'a', columnWidth: .25},
{html: 'b',columnWidth: .75}
]
```

What is the purpose of the **hbox** layout?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is difference beetween layout:'hbox' and loyout:'column'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311024/what-is-difference-beetween-layouthbox-and-loyoutcolumn)

Answer (score 1):

The **hbox** layout have more configs. but the **column** layout has less configs
 and **column** layout inherited from **Ext.layout.container.Auto**

the hbox layout have additional configs like

1. flex
2. align
3. pack
4. padding
   5...