# In Extjs, what's the difference between column layout and hbox layout?

Tags: extjs, layout

In my opinion, they are same. they are both horizontal layout.Column layout uses columnWidth to divide a container into many parts, and hbox uses flex to divide. In fact, ColumnWidth and flex are the same with percentage. 
  After all, what's the condition can i use column layout or hbox layout?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between column and hBox layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808474/difference-between-column-and-hbox-layout)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this discussion [Column vs Hbox layout](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?76642-ColumnLayout-versus-HBoxLayout)